# Find an envelope of the list of points

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration

I have a list of points as you can see in the image below. From this list of points, I want to generate a filtered list of points, which is the envelope. Additionally, calculate the area under the envelope.
[image]

```
rawData = {{1.`, 1.`}, {0.6666666666666666`, 
    0.9316770186335404`}, {0.5`, 0.906832298136646`}, {0.5`, 
    0.8757763975155279`}, {0.5`, 0.8633540372670807`}, {0.5`, 
    0.8509316770186336`}, {0.5`, 0.7888198757763976`}, {0.5`, 
    0.7142857142857143`}, {0.5`, 0.6645962732919255`}, {0.5`, 
    0.577639751552795`}, {0.3333333333333333`, 
    0.5341614906832298`}, {0.3333333333333333`, 
    0.453416149068323`}, {0.16666666666666666`, 
    0.36024844720496896`}, {0.16666666666666666`, 
    0.2670807453416149`}, {0.`, 0.21739130434782608`}, {0.`, 
    0.18633540372670807`}, {0.`, 0.13664596273291926`}, {0.`, 
    0.09937888198757763`}, {0.`, 0.062111801242236024`}, {0.`, 
    0.055900621118012424`}, {0.`, 0.`}};

points={{1.`,1.`},{0.6666666666666666`,0.9316770186335404`},{0.5`,0.906832298136646`},{0.3333333333333333`,0.5341614906832298`},{0.16666666666666666`,0.36024844720496896`},{0.`,0.21739130434782608`}};

Show[ListPlot[rawData, PlotStyle -> Red], ListLinePlot[points]]
f = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{l, u} = Transpose[Through[{First, Last}@#] & /@ GatherBy[SortBy[rawData, Last], First]];
{f1, f2} = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1]& /@ {l, u}
NIntegrate[f2[t] - f1[t], {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
```

> 0.101967

Alternatively,

```
RegionMeasure@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Polygon[Join[Reverse@l, u]]]
```

> 0.101967

```
ListPlot[{rawData, l, u}, Joined -> {False, True, True}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `InterpolationOrder -> 1`; otherwise the integral will be wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Henrik.

Answer (score 5):

Here another way, using the three-argument version of `GroupBy`:

```
a = KeySort[GroupBy[rawData, First -> Last, MinMax]];
lower = Values[a][[All, 1]];
upper = Values[a][[All, 2]];
t = Keys[a];
Show[
 ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{t, upper}], Transpose[{t, lower}]}],
 ListPlot[rawData, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]

And since these functions are piecewise-linear, we can apply Tai's method directly to obtain the integral exactly:

```
ω = 0.5 (Join[#, {0.}] + Join[{0.}, #]) &@Differences[t];
(upper - lower).ω
```

> 0.101967

Comment: "Tai's method" - :D

Answer (score 2):

If you assume "envelope" means the "shrink wrap" of the points, the answer is:

```
ConvexHullMesh[rawData]
```

If you want to get the area under the curve, add a point at {1,0}.

```
myRegion = ConvexHullMesh[rawData];
```

[image]

Get the area:

```
RegionMeasure[myRegion]
```

(* 0.757764 *)

Get the coordinates:

```
MeshCoordinates[myRegion]
```

(*

```
{{1., 1.}, {0.5, 0.906832}, {0., 0.217391}, {0., 0.186335}, 
 {0., 0.136646}, {0., 0.0993789}, {0., 0.0621118}, {0., 0.0559006}, 
 {0., 0.}, {1., 0.}}
```

*)

```
Show[HighlightMesh[myRegion, Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[MeshCoordinates[myRegion]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. How I get the boundary points from the ConvexHull

Comment: The problem with this is that by design, it will miss dips or troughs in the data.

Comment: It all comes down to what the poser means by "envelope."  I assumed the Convex Hull.

Comment: A bit hard to explain since I am on mobile, but I will try. Look at kglr's answer. In particular, notice the green line in his answer. A convex hull approach will not be able to reproduce that.