# How to find the area under many curves imported from excel

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm quite new to Mathematica. I need to calculate the area below many curves imported from excel.

I wrote this code:

curve={{{0,0},{0.1,1},{0.2,10},{0.22,20},{0.3,50},{0.4,20}},{{0,0},{0.15,5},{0.25,10},{0.27,20},{0.3,40},{0.5,30}}};

(*plot*) dataPlot =Table [ListLinePlot[l, PlotRange -> All], {l, curve}]

(*find the interpolating curves*) f = Table[Interpolation[l, InterpolationOrder -> 1], {l, curve}];

I've originally written the code for one curve, and I don't know how to write this last part of the code for n curves:

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, Max@x}]

NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, Max@x}]

I would also need to calculate the areas between 0 and the x values which correspond to the maximum y values

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. What is your estimation of the area for `curve[[1]]` and `curve[[2]]` ? Specifically, why are you trying to interpolate first and then use `NIntegrate` instead of just summing up?

Comment: Similar to [183935](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183933/find-an-envelope-of-the-list-of-points/183935#183935).

Answer (score 3):

```
curve = {{{0, 0}, {0.1, 1}, {0.2, 10}, {0.22, 20}, {0.3, 50}, {0.4, 
     20}}, {{0, 0}, {0.15, 5}, {0.25, 10}, {0.27, 20}, {0.3, 
     40}, {0.5, 30}}};
plots = Table[
  ListLinePlot[l, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis], {l, curve}]
DiscretizeGraphics /@ plots // Area
```

[image]

> `{7.2, 9.325}`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time. Your method is good, but unfortunately, it takes too much time when you have to work with experimental curves that involve hundreds of points.